The Binary Counter Turmite
For 2D Turing Machines, or Turmites (MathWorld, Wikipedia) the best known is Langton's Ant. An ant is on a grid of white/gray 0/1 squares. If white, turn right, otherwise turn left, change the color and move ahead one cell.

Less known is the Binary Counter. If white, turn right, change the color and move ahead one cell. It moves straight ahead over gray cells. On a blank grid, this rule starts counting in binary.

If the initial grid isn't blank, there are four behaviors: vertical counting, horizontal counting, cross counting and chaos. Starting with the 16 possible $2\times2$ grids, here are the behaviors after 10000 steps.

Here's the chaotic state after a million steps.

And here's the chaotic state after ten million steps.

And now the question. For the binary counter turmite, is there an initial condition where it goes into a chaotic state but then recovers into predictable counting?

Initial thoughts: It's easy to set up a line of gray squares that will pull the ant arbitrarily far out of the chaos while also wiping away the line. However, at the end of the line, the ant will start counting in the direction of the line, causing it to eventually hit the blob again. If there was some way to terminate the line that would turn the ant 90° and make it start counting perpendicular to the line, the answer would be yes. However, whenever the ant turns, it leaves behind a grey square, and making it not hit that square and turn 90° again seems… challenging. Maybe even impossible.
